# Logo in Navigation css

Tags: php, css

I have tried to place a logo/image floating left, inside my navigation bar. I have managed to place a image inside the navigation, but i have had no luck trying to make it float left. Can someone please help me.

I would like it to look like this: http://tinypic.com/r/2ep56rm/8

I have a index.php a header.php and my style.css.

First my header.php:

```
 <!--Begin Header-->
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="navigation"><!--Begin Navigation-->
  <img src="/images/toptop.jpg" width="220" height="50"/></a1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.php">Referencer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><!--End Navigation-->
  <!--End Header-->
```

and index.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Forside</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Free PHP Website Template from Redefined Web Design"          />
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
 <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"         />
 </head>

 <body>
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>


 <div id="wrapper"><!--Begin Wrapper-->
 <div id="container"><!--Begin Container-->

 <div id="mainContent"><!--Begin Main Content-->
 <h1>App udvikling i aller højeste klasse!</h1>
 <p></p>
 <p>Er du interesseret i at få et uforpligtende tilbud, så skal du være mere end      velkommen til at skrive til os og beskrive dine ønsker!</p>
 <h1>Udvikling af apps - så enkelt gør vi det</h1>
 <p></p>
 </div><!--End Main Content-->

  <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

and last my style.css:

```
  /*
  Free PHP Theme by: Redefined Web Design
  Description: Designed by <a href="http://www.redefinedwebdesign.com">Dallas Web     Design</a>
  Version: 2.0
  Author: <a href="http://www.redefinedwebdesign.com">Redefined Web Design</a>
  */

  /* Some people like to have CSS Reset files. If you choose to use one, place it here     above the general elements. */
  /* You will need to define some styles of the elements you reset below */


  /* General Elements */
  body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 100%; 
background: #000; 
text-align: left; 
margin: 0px;    
padding: 0px; 
color: #FFF;
 }
 #header {
height: 0px;    
background: url(/images/toppen.jpg);    
margin: 0px auto; 

 }
#navigation {
    background: url(/images/toppen.png);    
text-align:right;
    padding: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ea7c04;}

#navigation img { float: left;
  margin: 0px 160px;
 }

#navigation ul  { float: right; 
margin: 0px 180px 0px 100px;}

#navigation ul li {
list-style: none; 
display: inline; 
padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 30px;
}
#navigation ul li a {
color: #FFF; 
    font-size: 108%;
text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover
{
color: #ea7c04;
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0px auto;   
    background: #000 repeat-x;

}
#container {
background: url(/images/gradient.jpg); 
width: 100%;    
margin: 0px 0px auto; 
overflow: hidden;
}
#mainContent {
padding: 40px 0px 40px 180px; 
float: left; 
    min-height: 500px;
}
#sidebar {
padding: 0px 80px; 
    background: url(/images/gradient.jpg); 
float: right; 
    height: 500px;
width: 259px; 
border-left: 1px solid #ea7c04;
    margin: 40px 0px 40px;
}
#sidebar a img{
border: 0px solid #FFF;
border-radius:5px;
}
#social {
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0px 10px;
}
#social a img {
padding: 0px 5px;
border: none;
}
#footer {
height: 30px; 
    background: url(/images/toppen.png);    
    text-align: center; 
margin: 0px auto; 
    font-size: 90%; 
padding: 10px 0px; 
clear: both;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
}

 /* Typography */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family: Sans-serif; width: 650px;
}
h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family: Sans-serif; width: 650px;
font-style:italic;}
h1 {font-size: 160%;
margin: 0px 0px 20px;
color: #000;}
h2 {font-size: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 20px;
color: #000;}
h3 {font-size: 120%;
margin: 0px 0px 20px;}

p {font-size: 90%;
width: 650px;
margin: 0px 0px 20px;
color: #000;
font-family: Sans-serif;}

p9 {font-family: Sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color: #000;
margin: 0px 0px 0px;
line-height: 1.7;
font-size: 90%;}

p10 {font-family: Sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 90%;
color: #000;}

p11 {font-family: Sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color: #000;
margin: 0px 0px 20px;
line-height: 2.0;
font-size: 90%;
}

p12 {font-family: Sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color: #000;
margin: 0px 0px 0px;
line-height: 2.0;
font-size: 95%;
}

p13 {font-size: 90%;
margin: 0px 10px 0px;
color: #FFF;
font-family: Sans-serif;}

p14 {font-size: 100%;
margin: 0px 10px 0px;
color: #ea7c04;
font-family: Sans-serif;}

li{font-size: 90%;
margin: 0px 20px 20px;
color: #000;}

a {text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
a1 {text-decoration: none; color: #000;
margin: 0px 0px 0px;}
#sidebar h3 {font-size: 110%; margin-bottom: -7px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect, Correct it as follows :-

```
<div id="header"></div>
  <div id="navigation"><!--Begin Navigation-->
  <img src="/images/face.jpg" width="200" height="100"/>
  <ul>        
    <li><a href="/">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.php">Referencer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><!--End Navigation-->
```

---

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5S6N/1/)

CSS :

```
#navigation {
   padding: 0px;
}
#navigation img { float: left; }
#navigation ul  { float: right; }
```

Comment: I see. But i cant seem to place it in the left side? Have tried float:left and also with margin, but it wont move left?

Comment: Is ur `img` coming centered aligned?

Comment: See the edited answer...you need to clear ur `padding`.

Comment: It is now placed in the left side. I would like it to be placed align with the text in the navigation bar if possible. Cant seem to get it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation img {float: left;}
```

Comment: Our answer should be merged.

Comment: `mergeAnswers(yours, mine);`